# Keeping/restoring default dark mode setting after app update

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-dark-theme

I'm implementing new Android 10 feature called Dark Mode, some doc in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme). It is suggesting this line for switching:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(mode);
```

And this is working fine (on, off, system) - I'm installing debug app, setting proper mode in my apps settings, all `Activities` restarts themed as desired. I can quit app, force close, get back and my setting is still there. Problem is when I again build apk and install (even without any code change, just Shift + F10 in AS) then `getDefaultNightMode()` returns `MODE_NIGHT_UNSPECIFIED` which is default setting and which is falling back to system depend according to sources. Looks like future app updates will reset dark mode. How can I prevent that, do I miss something?

PS. Yeah, I could store set mode by own and force bring back when `AppCompatDelegate` will return default mode, but check out this note from above linked doc:

> Note: Starting with AppCompat v1.1.0, setDefaultNightMode() automatically recreates any started activities.

I don't want to blink UI (potentially) at first launch after every update...

Comment: do you just want to change the colors? Do you want it to only change when the user changes to dark mode or should there be a setting inside your app?

Comment: there should be setting in my app with three options: on, off and system-depend. And it is there, working well, switching themes. But falling back to default system-depend option when new version/update install